# How do I get the underlying SOAP document from a WebHookHandler

Tags: c#, webhooks

I'm trying to get the underlying SOAP document that this webhook handler is receiving

```
public class Myclass: WebHookHandler
{

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {

        var f = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             // this returns a blank string

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, most of the handlers in the Request object seem to be suspiciously blank.

Comment: Why are you making this call synchronously? You are in an async method, you should simply await the _ReadAsStringAsync_ call. It probably won't change anything, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

After some work, I've found that in the case of a Salesforce webhook, the underlying soap message can be achieved by typecasting the context.Data value to the SalesforceNotifications object that comes alone with the Salesforce Webhook library.

```
           var msg = (SalesforceNotifications) context.Data;   
           var soapmsg = msg.Document;
```

But this assumes that the message is caught and properly handled. It doesn't really answer my original question. I'm still looking for the answer of how I can intercept the HTTP message before it gets parsed and chopped up.